# Creating horizontal RecyclerView with circular scroll

Tags: javascript, android

I have a recyclerview with five items say n1,n2,n3,n4,n5.My requirement is on scrolling from the last item it should come to n1.

If anyone have the solution please share your code

Note : While coming to the first position from last it should not create new item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your getItemCount function in Adapter class use `return Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Also use position as below in bindviewholder function.

```
int positionInList = position % yourList.size();
```

Comment: above answer will create more copies of the same items.It should not happen,I need to use the same items

Comment: @tintomathew it will create "n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n1,n2..." - exactly what you want

Comment: I want to reuse the existing items in the view,It should not create more than five items.Now it's creating new item while scrolling with the same data...

Comment: In the above solution it will allow scrolling to one side.So I added the following line to make it both direction..recycler_view_list.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);